# dynamics crm 2016 use Microsoft.Xrm.Tooling.Connector in plugin

Tags: plugins, connection, dynamics-crm-2016, tooling

In Dynamics CRM 2016 on-premise, I need to read in a plugin some information from another Dynamics CRM 2016 on-premise.
I am trying to use use Microsoft.Xrm.Tooling.Connector to get a CrmServiceClient object for getting information from the remote Dynamics CRM.

I can register the plugin but when the step of the plugin is triggered I receive an error message:
Business Process Error
*Impossible de charger le fichier ou l'assembly 'Microsoft.Xrm.Tooling.Connector, Version=2.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' ou une de ses dépendances. Le fichier spécifié est introuvable.*

I want to know if this is the right way to get information from another CRM in the context of a plugin, and how can I resolve the above error.

Thank you
Radu

Answer (score 0):

The `Microsoft.Xrm.Tooling.Connector.dll` is not available on the CRM Server, because it is a client-side library.

You need to make it available on the server by adding it (and any dependencies) to the GAC (on each CRM server) or including it with the assembly using ILMerge.

Comment: Thank you very much, I have used ILMerge and now it's ok